# Collision with two lines of code make code does not work the way it is meant by me, what could I do different to get this work(?)

Tags: autohotkey

Try running the following code yourself, and you would notice that "can't" changes to "CAN't", but I want it to change it to "CAN NOT". On the other hand, I want to keep the 1.st line of code, which changes "can" to "CAN". How could I achieve this(?)

```
::can::CAN
::can't::CAN NOT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove `'` from defaults [ending characters](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars)

```
#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;"/\,.?!`n `t
::can::CAN
::can't::CAN NOT
```