# Collision with two lines of code makes code does not work the way it is meant by me(?)

Tags: autohotkey

Try running the following code yourself, and you would notice that "/hello" changes to "/HELLO", but I want it to change it to "hi". On the other hand, I want to keep the 1.st line of code, which changes "hello" to "HELLO". How could I achieve this(?)

This code problem is very related to my last problem:

[Collision with two lines of code make code does not work the way it is meant by me, what could I do different to get this work(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533561/collision-with-two-lines-of-code-make-code-does-not-work-the-way-it-is-meant-by/56534939#56534939)

The soltuion for my last problem was good for that problem, but it is not working for the new above mentioned problem.

```
::hello::HELLO
::/hello::hi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is interesting. I really expected it to work by removing `/` from the `EndChars`. But after looking at it for a while, it becomes obvious why it's behaving this way. When you type "/hello" it actually matches to both hotstrings, so AHK chooses the first one defined. Anyway, there are two solutions that I know of:

- Reorder your hotstrings. Place `::/hello::hi` above the other one and you'll always get the desired result. Additionally, you don't need to change the `EndChars` since `/` is the first character.
- Use the [asterisk option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) on the second hotstring. This will make it update immediately, which may or may not be desirable (I prefer it).